# X-men cartoon episode (or arc) with Cable and Apocalypse

Tags: marvel, x-men, episode-identification

The plot as I remembered is as follows:

- > Cable's children dies and he travels back in time.
- > Apocalypse prepares some sort of a disease, which will eventually kill Cable's children.
- > Cable destroys the virus caches and infects Wolverine. A serum is developed thanks to Wolverine's immune system.

Do you know which episodes fall into this arc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're describing the *X-Men: The Animated Series* episodes [*Time Fugitives* (Part 1)](https://marvel-90s-cartoons.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Fugitives_Part_1) and [*Time Fugitives* (Part 2](https://marvel-90s-cartoons.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Fugitives_Part_2)).

**[Part 1 opener](https://marvel-90s-cartoons.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Fugitives_Part_1)**

> Cable and Clan Chosen are fighting Apocalypse and his robots in the year, 3999 AD until a temporal storm devastates the city. Cable questions his A.I. about what's happening and it explains how Bishop travelled to the past and stopped [a disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_Virus) from spreading, meaning mutants would die. It further goes on to explain hoe Cable's timeline is going to cease to exist.

**[Part 2 ending](https://marvel-90s-cartoons.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Fugitives_Part_2)**

> Back at the X-Mansion, Beast examines Wolverine and finds that he has fully recovered from the plague, providing the anti-bodies Cable needed to save his timeline. Cable returns to his timeline to find that everything is restored to as before and Tyler is safe.